# Adding many data in QListView without "not responding"

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qlistview

for a project I need to integrate a lot of data in a QListView, I get the data from a QThread and store it in a QMap<QString, QString>, until then I have no problem of crash or freeze. But when in my QThread I browse my QMap to call for each element the function that will add the QString in the QListView, then I have a freeze. I searched a lot but I didn't find or understand how to do it. I add you a part of the simplified code to show you my problem :

exemple.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

#include "mythread.h"

class exemple : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit exemple(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QPushButton *btn_start;
    QListView *lv_file;
    QMap<QString, QString> myMap;
    MyThread *m_thread;
    QStandardItemModel *model;

public slots:
    void addFileInformation(QString, QString);
    void startShow();

private slots:
    void startThread();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mythread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDirIterator>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(QObject *parent);
    void run();

signals:
    void addFileInformation(QString, QString);
    void startShow();

};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

exemple.cpp

```
#include "exemple.h"

exemple::exemple(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(750,750);

    btn_start = new QPushButton("start", this);
    btn_start->setGeometry(50, 40, 150, 30);
    btn_start->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);

    lv_file = new QListView(this);
    lv_file->setGeometry(50, 100, 600, 500);

    m_thread = new MyThread(this);
    model = new QStandardItemModel(this);

    lv_file->setModel(model);

    connect(btn_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startThread()));
    connect(m_thread, SIGNAL(addFileInformation(QString, QString)),this, SLOT(addFileInformation(QString, QString)));
    connect(m_thread, SIGNAL(startShow()),this, SLOT(startShow()));
}

void exemple::startThread(){
    m_thread->start();
}

void exemple::addFileInformation(QString param1, QString param2)
{
    myMap.insert(param1, param2);
}

void exemple::startShow(){

    for (int i = 0; i < myMap.size(); i++){
        model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(myMap.keys()[i]));
    }
}
```

In this example it would be when the thread calls the startShow slot that my freeze appears.

I understand that I'm not in the thread anymore and that's the reason of the freeze but I have the same problem if instead of adding information to a QMap on "exemple" as I do here, the addFileInformation slot of example.cpp displayed directly the information. Like this:

exemple.cpp

```
void exemple::addFileInformation(QString param1, QString param2)
{
    model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(param1));
}
```

If you have a solution, a track or a link to do this without freezing I'm interested :)

If I'm not clear don't hesitate to ask me to explain it again, thanks to those who will take their time to help me.

Comment: `myMap.keys()[i]` - this is a linear search and creates a new temporary QList evey time for no reason. Properly iterate through the QMap with iterators to avoid this quadratic runtime behavior.

Comment: @chehrlic I have corrected this thanks you but it doesn't allow me to avoid the freeze

Comment: If you've a large dataset don't use a convenience model but an own derived from QAbstractTableModel - then you can insert the data much more efficient (even in a thread when you swap the model in the gui thread later on but I doubt this is needed)

Comment: I will look into this as well, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is large, you probably need to implement your own model that uses the data in the fashion you're storing it. Models in Qt are tricky, but once you've done a few they begin to make sense.

I've got an example on my github: https://github.com/jplflyer/qt-TreeViewDemo. It's probably not perfect. I wrote it while trying to figure out how to write it. This is for `QTreeView`, but `QListView` won't be that different.

I also have a generic version here: https://github.com/jplflyer/Git-Dashboard. Look down into the tree for `GenericItemModel`. It's a template and is kind of cool, actually. It also may not be fully featured, but it might help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll go and have a look at it, I didn't think it was possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unset model from view `lv_file->setModel(nullptr);` to get rid of unnecessary view refreshes (after each row insert), change model and set it back to view.

Comment: Thank you for your help, indeed it is a good remark that I will adopt, but after testing it reduces the freeze time but it does not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a signal to send your mapdata to the ui thread and append a row in your thread, not just append a row directly in your thread.

i have review u code carefully,and maybe u should try this way:

```
void exemple::startShow()

    { 
    QList<QStandardItem*> itemList; 
    for (int i = 0; i < myMap.size(); i++)
    { itemList<<(new QStandardItem(myMap.keys()[i])); 
    } 
    model->appendRow(itemList); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not sure I understand, pass my QMap created in "example" in my thread? In this case I won't be able to fill my QListView since I will be in my thread, and even if I reuse my QMap in "example" once the thread is finished, I will be obliged to browse the QMap to make the insertions so the problem will still be present.

Comment: trying to insert a list like this into the model doesn't work as you would have to go through all the elements of the list to insert them into the QList (which produces a freeze)

Comment: use void QStandardItemModel::setRowCount(int rows) with myMap.size,if not work ,u have to inherited from QAbstractListModel and overwrite data(),rowCount()...